# tr equivalent Linux Command to replace a string without editing the file

Tags: linux, sed, tr

tr is a command to replace a single character but I am looking for a command line solution to replace **\001 with |** in a log file for better readability of the line. I dont want to edit the file with a command which modifies the log file.

input: **FIX.4.2\0019=64\00135=0\00134=363**

output intended: **FIX.4.2|9=64|35=0|34=363**

Comment: *Why* do you not want to use `sed`?

Comment: `sed` is the obvious tool for the job.  It doesn't overwrite the input file unless you tell it to do so.  Why the resistance to using the proper tool for the job?  I suppose you can use `awk`; it will be harder to write than using `sed`.  You can use Perl or Python too.  But `sed` has the 'replace string without editing file' written into its job title — the overwrite stuff is a recent addition to non-standard versions of `sed` (recent meaning since about 1990).  (This command should do the job — `sed 's/\\001/|/g'` — and it is compact notation too!)

Comment: I didnt mean to not use sed but my understanding is it replaces the existing log file.

Comment: No (`sed` does not replace the existing log file).  GNU `sed` and BSD (macOS) `sed` have flags to allow you to overwrite the input file(s), but by default, `sed` edits the stream of input (its name is an abbreviation of 'stream editor') and writes to standard output.  You have to tell it to overwrite the input.  (The `awk` equivalent is longer than the `sed`: ` awk '{gsub(/\\001/, "|"); print}'` — which could be reduced to `awk '{gsub(/\\001/, "|")} 1'` if you prefer brevity to clarity.  The Perl is pretty compact to: `perl -pe 's/\\001/|/g'`.)

Comment: `sed` with the `-i` flag will replace the file, otherwise it just sends the results to `stdout` or you can redirect to another file. `sed <whatever> infile > outfile`. You could also swap delimiters with `awk` pretty easily if `sed` is still deemed off limits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `sed` is the obvious way to do the job. It doesn't overwrite the input file unless you tell it to do so.

I suppose you can use `awk`; it will be (a little) harder to write than using `sed`. You can use Perl or Python too. But `sed` has the 'replace string without editing file' written into its job title — the overwrite stuff is a recent addition to non-standard versions of sed (recent meaning since about 1990).

This command should do the job — and it is compact notation too!

```
sed 's/\\001/|/g'
```

> but my understanding is it replaces the existing log file.

No — `sed` does not replace the existing log file. Both GNU `sed` and BSD (macOS) `sed` have the `-i` flag to allow you to overwrite the input file(s) — but the semantics of their `-i` flags are slightly different.  However, by default, `sed` edits the stream of input (its name is an abbreviation of 'stream editor') and writes to standard output. You have to tell it to overwrite the input.

The awk equivalent is longer than the sed:

```
awk '{gsub(/\\001/, "|"); print}'
```

which (if you prefer brevity to clarity) could be reduced to:

```
awk '{gsub(/\\001/, "|")} 1'
```

The Perl is pretty compact too:

```
perl -pe 's/\\001/|/g'
```

For completeness, a Python 2.7 script for this job could be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re
import fileinput

match = re.compile(r'\\001')

for line in fileinput.input():
    line = re.sub(match, '|', line)
    print line,
```

(See [fileinput](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html), [re](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) and [print](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print) for syntax details — the trailing comma *does* matter.)

The equivalent in Python 3.x is very similar:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import re
import fileinput

match = re.compile(r'\\001')

for line in fileinput.input():
    line = re.sub(match, '|', line)
    print(line, end='')
```

(See [fileinput](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html), [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) and [print](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) for more information.  Note that `print()` versus `print` is one of the biggest differences between Python 2 and Python 3.)

There may be better ways to write the Python code.  It seems to work, though.

Answer (score 2):

Redirect output with sed to a new file without changing original file:

```
sed 's/\\001/|/g' file > new_file
```

Output to `new_file`:

```
FIX.4.2|9=64|35=0|34=363
```